# Is it possible to use the value of a vector as the name of another vector?

Tags: r

suppose I have a vector:

```
outYr
```

in a loop with the value of outYr changing every time it loops:

```
require(Metrics)
    itrcnt <- 10
     count  <- 0
    x <- c(1:99)
    y <- (2:100)
    for( i in 1:itrcnt)
     {
        outYr = 1998 + count
        print(paste(outYr,'has been excluded'))
        RMSE(outYr value) <- rmse(x,y)
        count <-count + 1
     }
```

I wish to use the value of outYr at the end of the loop as a name for another vector, for example:

```
RMSE(outYr value) <- rmse(x,y)
```

would end up looking like

```
RMSE1998 <- rmse (x,y)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Edit1: I have been pointed toward using `paste()` and will update if I can figure it out.

Comment: (1) Using that example, `1998rmse` is not normally a legal R variable name. You can still assign it, but you'll need to reference it with backticks all of the time, as in `\`1998rmse\``. This can be mitigated by starting with a letter. (2) You can use `assign` for that, but that practice is generally discouraged (as prone to errors). It is generally best to do things in a named-`list`, where this might be `alldat <- lapply(1998 + sel_len(itrcnt), function(outYr) rmse(x, y))`, and then reference `alldat[["1999"]]`. (There will be no 1998 from your sequencing, btw.)

Comment: That would mitigate my first point above about the variable name. If you really want to do it that way, then [`?assign`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) is what you need. There are very few times I have found that `assign` is the "right/best" way to go; at least 99% of the time, I feel it is better to work with a `list` than iterate and `assign` in a `for` loop. And when not done well, troubleshooting anything that uses `assign` can be really difficult.

Comment: @r2evans were I to change the variable name to RMSE1998, how would that reference change?

Comment: What is `x` and `y` in `rmse(x, y)` and from which package does the function `rmse` comes from?

Comment: @RonakShah I added required package and meaning to x and y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initialized an empty list:

```
RMSE <-list()
```

Then  filled the indices in the loop:

```
require(Metrics)
    itrcnt <- 10
     count  <- 0
    RMSE <- list()
    x <- c(1:99)
    y <- (2:100)
    for( i in 1:itrcnt)
     {
        outYr = 1998 + count
        print(paste(outYr,'has been excluded'))
        RMSE[count +1] <- rmse(x,y)
        count <-count + 1
     }
```